# Flutter: image_picker fails when you run pub get

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, imagepicker, flutter-image

Here is my pubspec.yaml
When I run pub get without image picker, it works.

```
name: project1
description: A new Flutter application.

publish_to:
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk:  ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  camera:
  image_picker: ^0.6.1+4


  image_cropper:
  path_provider:
  path:
  flutter_local_notifications: ^1.4.4+2
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


flutter:

 uses-material-design: true
 assets:
```

But when I include image_picker from latest version to 0.6.0 it shows the same error message

> The plugin `flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle` doesn't have a main class defined in C:\Users\john\Documents\flutter_windows_1.17.1-stable\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle-1.0.8\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle\FlutterAndroidLifecyclePlugin.java or C:\Users\john\Documents\flutter_windows_1.17.1-stable\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle-1.0.8\android\src\main\kotlin\io\flutter\plugins\flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle\FlutterAndroidLifecyclePlugin.kt. This is likely to due to an incorrect `androidPackage: io.flutter.plugins.flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle` or `mainClass` entry in the plugin's pubspec.yaml.
> If you are the author of this plugin, fix the `androidPackage` entry or move the main class to any of locations used above. Otherwise, please contact the author of this plugin and consider using a different plugin in the meanwhile.

I tried running other projects w/o image_picker and they seem to work fine. I just can't install the image_picker.

Comment: try reverting to an older version of image_picker

Comment: I went back as far as 0.6.0.... still gives the same error output

Comment: Follow this: [Flutter Image/Video Picker Medium Post](https://www.codementor.io/@ponnamkarthik3/flutter-image-video-picker-flutter-karthik-ponnam-medium-yqt9kjrvb)

Comment: I followed that. still got the same fail message from pub get

Answer (score 0):

I tried importing in Flutter 1.17.5 • channel stable. It's working fine. Can you upgrade flutter and try again?

Answer (score 0):

Delete `.pub-cache`  folder

Run `flutter pub get` command

If this doesn't work try

Adding `flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle` dependency in your yaml file

delete `.pub-cache` folder

run `flutter pub get` command

Answer (score 0):

Adding `flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle` dependencies and running

```
dart pub cache repair
```

or

```
flutter pub cache repair
```

worked for me.