# Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-packages

i tried everything i could to import **image_picker** and i find on various sites but couldn't get rid of this error :

```
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
```

> Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart'.
> Try creating the file referenced by the URI, or Try using a URI for a file that does exis

already added the dependencies such as :

```
     dependencies:
       
       image_picker: ^0.8.4+8
```

Running "flutter pub get" it turns out to

**OUTPUT:**

> The plugin `flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle` doesn't have a main
> class defined in C:\Users\Iradukunda
> Didier\Documents\flutter_windows_2.8.1-stable\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle-2.0.5\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle\FlutterAndroidLifecyclePlugin.java
> or C:\Users\Iradukunda
> Didier\Documents\flutter_windows_2.8.1-stable\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle-2.0.5\android\src\main\kotlin\io\flutter\plugins\flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle\FlutterAndroidLifecyclePlugin.kt.
> This is likely to due to an incorrect `androidPackage: io.flutter.plugins.flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle` or `mainClass`
> entry in the plugin's pubspec.yaml. If you are the author of this
> plugin, fix the `androidPackage` entry or move the main class to any
> of locations used above. Otherwise, please contact the author of this
> plugin and consider using a different plugin in the meanwhile.  exit
> code 1

Comment: Check if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/66552660

Answer (score 0):

Run `flutter packages get` instead of `flutter pub get`. If it does not work, Re-start the Visual Studio Code after `flutter packages get`

[Source:](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages)